# How to justify text properly in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, alignment, jspdf

I am facing an issue with using the [jsPDF library](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html). While I am able to generate PDFs fine, I seem to not be able to properly justify text. The `align: 'justify'` property appears to behave equally to `align: 'left'` and the text is not aligned when setting `maxWidth` to a specific number. An exemplary code snippet:

```js
doc.text(
  "Lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet lorem ipsum solor dit samet",
  10,
  203,
  { align: "justify", lineHeightFactor: 1.5, maxWidth: 190 }
);
```

The output will not be justified and will simply be split at the specified `maxWidth`. I would highly appreciate any directions as to how to properly justify the rendered text.

Comment: did you manage to solve it? 

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution online, credits to https://youvcode.com/how-to-justify-text-in-pdf-using-jspdf/.

```
doc.text( 10,60,title,{maxWidth: 185, align: "justify"})
```

assuming title is a very long text